# Is there any way to use a member function of a class to run in a concurrent thread without passing *this in C++11?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, xcode4.6

I'm a novice in C++11 threading and trying use a member function of a class to run in concurrent threads.

In the answer to my earlier question I received the suggestion:

```
std::thread t1(&SomeClass::threadFunction, *this, arg1, arg2);
```

I implemented the above suggestion. It removed the compile error I was having but introduced a runtime error. In another question I received the suggestion to remove all copy mechanism. Actually, I don't want to copy the data, because the code is for Finite Element Analysis and require a lot of memory.

Is There any way I can do this?

The header is similar to the following.

```
SomeClass {
    vector<int*> someVariable;
public:
    ~SomeClass();
    void threadedMethod(bool, bool); // Inside this method the 
                                     // member vector 'someVariable' is used.

    void someMethod();               // In this function the threadedMethod has
                                     // been used twice to make 2 different thread
};
```

The someMethod implementation is,

```
void SomeClass::someMethod() {
    thread t1(&SomeClass::threadedMethod, *this, arg1, arg2);
    thread t2(&SomeClass::threadedMethod, *this, arg1, arg2);
    t2.join();
    t1.join();
}
```

The destructor is similar to the following,

```
SomeClass::~SomeClass() {
    int count  = someVariable.size();
    for(int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        delete someVariable[i];
    }
}
```

The threadMethod accesses the variable. The operations are data parallel. As a result, no thread will write in the same memory block. Again, the read and write memory is different. There for I think I don't need any kind of locks.

As you can see, I am using `*this` and that is causing a lot of copy. I really need to avoid it. Can any one kindly suggest any other way which will let me avoid the copying?

If you need more explanation please let me know. If within my ability I'll try to elaborate as much as possible.

I am using an Intel Mac with OS X 10.8.3. I'm coding on Xcode 4.6.1. The compiler is Apple LLVM 4.2 (default compiler).

Comment: Have you tried just passing `this` (instead of `*this`)?

Comment: @AndyProwl, could you please put it into the answer section? It works like magic. Thanks a lot. You saved my day (well, night :p).

Comment: I posted an answer :) Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments are passed *by value* to the constructor of `std::thread`. Therefore, this statement:

```
std::thread t1(&SomeClass::threadFunction, *this, arg1, arg2);
//                                         ^^^^^
```

Triggers a copy of `*this`, which is not what you want. However, `std::thread` can also accept a *pointer* to the object on which the member function shall be invoked, exactly like `std::bind`.

Therefore, by passing `this` (instead of `*this`) as an argument, it is the *pointer* - instead of the pointed object - that is going to be passed by value and eventually copied. This will trigger no copy construction of `SomeClass`, as you desire.

Thus, you should rewrite the above statement as follows:

```
std::thread t1(&SomeClass::threadFunction, this, arg1, arg2);
//                                         ^^^^
```